# Is it possible to compress multiple files into single zip and upload from Angular 5+

Tags: javascript, java, angular, file-upload, angular5

I want to upload multiple files (around 30) from angular 5+ frontend. I need it such that it combines and available for download as a single zip file.

Is frontend zipping and uploading recommended in angular? If not which is the recommended way.(The server backend is Java).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zip them in the Java backend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596651/zip-file-uploading-issue-in-angular-2

Comment: @Amrit, I have non-zip files that I want to combine and zip as one file to upload to server

Comment: @MauricePerry but , can we do it in frontend (angular). ?