# zip file uploading issue in angular and node js

Tags: node.js, angular, file, file-upload, zip

I am trying to upload a zip file which contain a number of json files, i need to read the zip file on server side and read the contents of it(json files). But i am getting bad request when trying to upload the zip file have tried all the possible solutions example [followed this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596651/zip-file-uploading-issue-in-angular-2/51597901) but i am getting bad request error since i have not done any file upload in angular and nodejs need some guidance. Below the code which i have written to upload the zip file and have created a api end point to see whats getting uploaded.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Choose File</label>
            <input type="file" id="file" #file(change)="importData(element.name,element.id,$event.target.files)">
        </div>
```

**TS file code**

```
  importData(name,id,files){


let fileList: FileList = files;
if (fileList.length > 0) {
  let file: File = fileList[0];
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
  formData.append('fileType', 'zip');
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  this.http.post('http://localhost:4400/data' + '/importConfiguration/newProd12345/1.0', formData, {headers: {"Accept": "application/json",enctype:"multipart/form-data"}})
    // .map(res => res.json())
    // .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .subscribe(
    data => console.log('success'),
    error => console.log(error)
    )
}}
```

**ERROR I AM GETTING ON SELECTING FILE AND MAKING UPLOAD REQUEST**

[image: 400 BAD REQUEST]

**CODE FOR GENERATING ZIP FILE**

```
router.get("/exportConfiguration/:productId/:productVersion", async (req, res) => {var productId=req.params.productId;var productVersion=req.params.productVersion; 
  var formulas= await getFormulas(productId,productVersion);
  var rules = await getRules(productId,productVersion)

  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=myFile.zip'
  });
  var zip = Archiver('zip');

  // Send the file to the page output.
  zip.pipe(res);

  // Create zip with some files. Two dynamic, one static. Put #2 in a sub folder.
  zip.append(JSON.stringify(formulas), { name: 'formulas.json' })
  .append(JSON.stringify(rules), { name: 'rules.json' })
      // .append('Some text to go in file 2. I go in a folder!', { name: 'somefolder/2.txt' })
      // .file('staticFiles/3.txt', { name: '3.txt' })
    .finalize();});
```

Any help of idea on how to solve this is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue of the json files. Which charset do they have and which charset is expected?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm have updated the question with the code for generating the zip file

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` header on the Angular request?

Comment: @WillAlexander yes tried it getting the same 400 bad request error